# Does this strict weak ordering have a name (spoilers for a specific coding puzzle)

Tags: string, puzzle, proof, lexicographic, strict-weak-ordering

There is a coding puzzle I have encountered on one of those sites (I don't recall if it was leetcode or something else) which goes as follows: Given a list of strings, return the lexicographically smallest concatenation that uses each of the strings once. The solution is, on a technical level, fairly simple. You compare 2 strings `a` and `b` by checking whether `ab<ba` (lexicographically), sort the list, concatenate everything.

Now for the actual question: Does this ordering have a name? I tried googling around but never found anything.

There is also a secondary aspect to this, which is: Is it somehow immediately obvious that this is even a strict weak ordering? I certainly didn't think it was. Here is the proof that I came up with to convince myself that it is one:

For any given string `s` let `|s|` be its length and let `s^n` be `s` repeated `n` times.
If `ab<ba` then `a^|b|b^|a|<b^|a|a^|b|` (to see this just successively swap neighboring `ab` pairs to get a lexicographically increasing sequence that ends in `b^|a|a^|b|`). It follows that `a^|b|<b^|a|` because they have the same length. The same argument works for `>` and `=` so we have proven that `ab<ba` is actually equivalent to `a^|b|<b^|a|`, with the latter clearly defining a strict weak ordering.